# Int64(long) in CosmosDB via MongoDB corrupted

Tags: mongodb, azure-cosmosdb

When inserting json with a int64(long) value to CosmosDB via MongoDB the value is saved as double in a corrupted format.

I'm inserting this json:

```
{
   "Foo" : NumberLong(636424438674296276)
}
```

It is saved in the collection with this invalid format:

```
{
    "Foo" : 6.36424438674296e+17.0
}
```

The invalid format causes queries on the collection to fail.

Any ideas how to correct this issue?

Answer (score 1):

The loss of precision is due to the use of old JSON schema in your account. Please re-create the account in Cosmos DB and re-populate collections in it, it should return 64-bit number without the issue. If not possible to recreate just shoot an email to askcosmosdb@microsoft.com with your subscriptioId/accountname and ask to enable new BSON schema.